# How to update a portion of the document in couch db using update function and CURL

Tags: couchdb

While performing an update in couch db document with a nested structure, the update function does not give desired output. It updates one of the fields but not the rest.

Update function is as follows

```
{
  "_id": "_design/prjupdate",
  "_rev": "48-f0ce642e0b4f6730cae40b0b9748b61c",
  "updates": {
    "updatebyid": "function(doc, req){\r\n  for(var idx in doc.reports) {\r\n  if (doc.reportId == null) {\r\n doc.reports[idx].reportId = req.query.reportId; \r\n doc.reports[idx].reportType = req['userCtx']['reportType']; \r\n doc.reports[idx].reportCreationDate = req.query.reportCreationDate; \r\n  return [doc, 'Created reportId'];\r\n}}}"
  }
}

CURL is curl -u <user:password> -X PUT http://<host:port>/projects/_design/prjupdate/_update/updatebyid/8b3aa3289291671ad4456ee6acaa5027?reportId=1000014&reportType="summary"&reportCreationDate="2015-12-14T00:00:00"


This updates only partially like

{
  "_id": "8b3aa3289291671ad4456ee6acaa5027",
  "_rev": "58-36e132d518cc00af42bb6e2245eae7e0",
  "name": "sruti1234",
  "reports": [
    {
      "reportId": "1000014"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I am able to update and add a new array to the existing document  {
  "_id": "_design/prjupdnew",
  "updates": {
    "updnew": "function(doc, req) {if (doc != null) {var data=JSON.parse(req.body); doc['reports']=data; return [doc, 'Added the requested fields'];} return [null, 'No such document'];}"
  }
}

Comment: But I am not able to add a new update inside an existing array without having to pass all the elements of the array

Answer (score 0):

I could resolve it using the following function

curl -u  -X PUT http:///projects/_design/prjupdrpt/_update/updrptctd/013efdccb137eef7b2dc854cdc0b9d0e?reportId=1000036 -d '{"toolName": "summary", "reportName": "summary", "reportScore": 75, "reportDate": "2020-01-15 07:22:41",  "reportStatus": "success", "guageRagLimits": [{"rangeStart": 0,"rangeEnd": 25,"rangeColour": "Green"},{"rangeStart": 25,"rangeEnd": 75,"rangeColour": "Amber"},{ "rangeStart": 75,"rangeEnd": 100,"rangeColour": "Red" }] }'

{
  "_id": "_design/prjupdrpt",
  "updates": {
    "updrptctd": "function(doc, req) {if (doc != null) {var data=JSON.parse(req.body); for(var idx in doc.reports) {if (doc.reports[idx].reportId==req.query.reportId) {doc.reports[idx].reportData.push(data); return [doc, 'Added the requested fields'];}}} return [null, 'No such document'];}"
  }
}